# Why does shell_exec into variable using PHP not work?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to run this but the variable `$new` is empty when I run it. When I run the ffmpeg command via command line it gives me the desired output, in fact when I run it in php I see the output from ffmpeg which I'm expecting to be put in the `$new` variable, but it's empty. Can anyone help me with the reason?

Thanks.

```
<?php
$new = shell_exec('ffmpeg -t 10 -i http://audiostream.com -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null');
file_put_contents('output.txt', $new);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I'm sure I tried this and it didn't work, but just tried it again and it does...

```
<?php
$new = shell_exec('ffmpeg -t 10 -i http://audiostream.com -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null 2>&1');
file_put_contents('output.txt', $new);
?>
```

Comment: You probably hit an error then. It says in the docs,if an error occurs (or no output is given, noting that stderr isn't used), null is returned, the fact that it works when you redirect stderr to stdout seems to confirm.

Comment: @omega1 the "2>&1" redirect error to std_out, too...